# Use pseudo elements to push the content to left, right, top, or bottom of the element in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations, pseudo-element, web-frontend

Is there a way to push the content of an element to the right using pseudo elements to get the result in the picture below ?

[image: Picture]

Right now, this is the html code:

```
<div class="center" style="background-color: cyan;">
    <div class="outside-right">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

And these are the CSS classes:

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.outside-right{
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

**The problem is with CSS animations when changing the transform property of an element, it will override the class `.outside-right` transform and the element will snap back to the center of its parent before starting the animation.**

So I have tried changing the `.outside-right` class, by putting the `::before` pseudo element with `width:100%` so it pushes the content of that element. But nothing seems to make it work.
I have tried:

CSS:

```
.outside-right-using-pseudo-element::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And

```
.outside-right-using-pseudo-element::before {
    content: '';
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="center" style="background-color: cyan;">
    <div class="outside-right-using-pseudo-element">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any possible way that make it work ?

Comment: use a code tester like jsfiddle or codepen to make changes quickly and instantly see the results

Comment: @TemaniAfif It doesn't work either. Also the pushed content needs to lie on the edge of its container so the width must be relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost good, add `white-space:nowrap;` to avoid having the element in the next line:

```css
.outside-right-using-pseudo-element {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.outside-right-using-pseudo-element::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
}

.outside-right-using-pseudo-element:hover::before {
  width: 0%;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="center" style="background-color: cyan;">
  <div class="outside-right-using-pseudo-element">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Another idea using flexbox:

```css
.outside-right-using-pseudo-element {
  display: flex;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.outside-right-using-pseudo-element::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* this will do the trick */
  align-self: flex-start;
  transition: 1s;
}

.outside-right-using-pseudo-element:hover::before {
  width: 0%;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="center" style="background-color: cyan;">
  <div class="outside-right-using-pseudo-element">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

And you can easily have the other direction:

```css
.outside-right-using-pseudo-element,
.outside-left-using-pseudo-element{
  display: flex;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.outside-left-using-pseudo-element,
.outside-bottom-using-pseudo-element{
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.outside-right-using-pseudo-element::before,
.outside-left-using-pseudo-element::after{
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* this will do the trick */
  align-self: flex-start;
  transition: 1s;
}

.outside-right-using-pseudo-element:hover::before,
.outside-left-using-pseudo-element:hover::after {
  width: 0%;
}

.center {
  display:table;
  margin:80px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center" style="background-color: cyan;">
  <div class="outside-left-using-pseudo-element">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="center" style="background-color: cyan;">
  <div class="outside-right-using-pseudo-element">
    Content content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But the first code (not the flexbox) introduces a little margin between the word "Content" and the cyan box, maybe due to the empty string in conten: '' beeing interpreted as a white space. Can't we just float the pseudo element to the left so It pushed the content to the right, and eliminate that margin ?

Comment: @user13695921 we cannot with float, it will push the content down and not to the right. You can use the flexbox approach where there is no white space issue

Comment: Can flexbox be used also to push the content to the right, top, or bottom ?

Comment: @user13695921 yes I added the right option ;) will update with the top and bottom also

Comment: Thank you. The flexbox solution works well if it can also be applied on top and bottom

Answer (score 0):

```css
        .outside-right-using-pseudo-element {
          position:relative;
          padding-left:110px
          
        }
        .outside-right-using-pseudo-element:before{
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background: cyan;
          
        }
```

```html
 
    <div class="center">
        <div class="outside-right-using-pseudo-element">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
```